# JavaScript sanitize HTML string and remove ID, class and other attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I need help to sanitize my HTML text provided by user. I have following HTML code:

```
var htmlStr = `<p id="test" class="mydemo">TEhis is test</p>
   <pre class="css">
      &lt;html>
          &lt;body class="test">&lt;/body>
      &lt;/html>
   </pre>`;
```

I want to remove ID, Class or any attribute from all the tags OTHER then `<PRE>` and `<CODE>` tags using plain JavaScript.

I tried following but not getting proper output:

```
sanitizeHtml(html: any) {
    let temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = html;
    // let t1 = temp.querySelectorAll('*');

    temp.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(node => {
        if(node.nodeName !== 'PRE') {
            return node.removeAttribute('id');
        }
    })

    console.log(temp);

    // return html.replace(/\s*(\w+)=\"[^\"]+\"/gim, '').replace(/<script>[\w\W\s\S]+<\/script>/gim);
}
```

Please let me know if you need further information on it.

Comment: Thanks @Neal, for correction. I tried lot to align code properly but not getting why it was merged with my text.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code is successfully removing the `id` attribute from the `<p>` tag, you just don't have any code there to remove any other attributes.

Comment: Hi @Herohtar, Later i checked that and as you mentioned it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little mechanical, and perhaps not the optimal solution, however you could achieve this by chaining `.replace()` with the following regular expressions to sanitise your HTML string as needed:

```js
   
function sanitizeHtml(html) {

  var htmlSanitized = html
  .replace(/<pre[\w\s"=]*>/gi, function(match) { 
      // Add a place holder to attrbitues on pre elements to prevent
      // removal of these in subsequent step
      return match.replace(/=/gi, 'EQUALS')
  })
  .replace(/\w+="\w+"/gi,'')
  .replace(/\s+>/gi,'>')
  .replace(/EQUALS/i,'=')

  return htmlSanitized;
}

var htmlStr = `<p id="test" class="mydemo">TEhis is test</p>
   <pre class="css">
      &lt;html>
          &lt;body class="test">&lt;/body>
      &lt;/html>
   </pre>`;

console.log(sanitizeHtml(htmlStr));
```

Comment: Hi @Dacre Denny, Thanks for your reply. 
Due to other tasks I was not able to test this solution but will try and update on the same.

Comment: @JigneshRaval no problems, hope this helps!